# How Do I Adjust Image Sizing To Stay Proportional

Tags: html, css, image, photo

I am completely new to creating a website using Wordpress but have realized that HTML coding seems to be easier than just dragging and dropping. I have done several things to address the issue however nothing has worked exactly how I'd like it to.

Basically what I'm looking to do is have one full-size image (same width as the justified paragraph above it). Below that single image, there would be a space and then there would be two images side by side with space in between. They would be half the width of the image above, and no matter how you scaled the web browser to be larger or smaller, it would keep the same proportions. Then I would have the same thing below with 3 images below.

Ideally, there would be an image thats 100% width, the next two below would be 50% each with space in between. The next three below would be 33%. All pictures would have even spacing in between. How can I do this?

Here are a couple of things I've tried that didn't work out:

1)

```
<p class="has-text-align-justify">
<img class="wp-image-460" style="width: NaNpx;" src="https://..." alt="">

<img class="wp-image-458" style="width: 387px;" src="..." alt=""> &nbsp;

<img class="wp-image-459" style="width: 387px;" src="..." alt="">

</p>
```

2)

```
<img src="https://..." style="float: left; width: 49%; margin-right: 1.0em; margin-bottom: 1.0em;">

<img src="https://..." style="float: left; width: 49%; float: right; margin-bottom: 1.0em;">
```

Comment: Use percentages (e.g. `style="width: 50%"`) on your `img` tag inside your tag container (e.g. a `div`) for half size, and 100% for full size.

Comment: Two images at 50% with space in between is more than 100% of the width of the container.

Comment: Are the images of the same size? Can one image be 500x50 px and another be 70x200 px?

Comment: @rickardelimää - in regards to the two 50% images with a space being more than one 100% imagine, that's what i thought. when i try to do 49.5%, it doesnt work. it is either 49% or 50%; is there any way to change this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Ideally, there would be an image thats 100% width, the next two below
>   would be 50% each with space in between. The next three below would be
>   33%. All pictures would have even spacing in between. How can I do
>   this?

**CSS Flexbox** is the perfect tool to achieve what you're describing.

You can:

- create three containers, each with `display: flex`
- place one image in the first container, two in the second and three in the third
- give each image a `flex` value of `flex: 1 0 30%`

`flex` is a shorthand value, short for `flex-grow`, `flex-shrink`, `flex-basis`.

Here the instruction `flex: 1 0 30%` means:

- `flex-grow` priority of `1` - ie. grow when you don't fill the space
- `flex-shrink` priority of `0` - ie. do not shrink, no matter how much or how little space there is
- `flex-basis` of `30%` - use `30%` of your parent as your starting width, before growing or shrinking

**Working Example:**

```css
.image-container-row {
  display: flex;
}

img {
  flex: 1 0 30%;
  height: 45px;
  margin: 6px;
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<div class="image-container">

<div class="image-container-row">
<img class="wp-image-455" alt="Image - 100%">
</div>

<div class="image-container-row">
<img class="wp-image-456" alt="Image - 50%">
<img class="wp-image-457" alt="Image - 50%">
</div>


<div class="image-container-row">
<img class="wp-image-458" alt="Image - 33%">
<img class="wp-image-459" alt="Image - 33%">
<img class="wp-image-460" alt="Image - 33%">
</div>

</div>
```

---

## Follow-up exercises to practise `flex`:

[Flexbox Froggy - a game for learning flexbox](https://flexboxfroggy.com/)

Answer (score 0):

Another example, using `flex`. The downside with my solution is that you will get some spacing to the left and right of the images, but the same happens with Rounin's solution.

Clarifications are within the CSS code below.

```css
.container {
  display: flex;    /* display all children in a one-dimensional list */
  flex-wrap: wrap;  /* wrap child elements if it's needed */
}

.container > img {
  width: calc(100%/3);
  padding-bottom: 1rem;   /* 1rem = the font size of the document */
  padding-left: 0.5rem;   /* flex can take padding into consideration ... */
  padding-right: 0.5rem;  /* ... in comparison to using margin but ... */
  box-sizing: border-box; /* ... we need to set this value too */
}

.container > img:nth-child(1) {   /* first child in .container */
  width: 100%;
}

.container > img:nth-child(2),
.container > img:nth-child(3) {   /* second and third child in container */
  width: 50%;
}
```

```html
<p class="has-text-align-justify">Hello world</p>

<div class="container">
  <img src="https://i.picsum.photos/id/11/200/200.jpg">

  <img src="https://i.picsum.photos/id/22/200/200.jpg">
  <img src="https://i.picsum.photos/id/33/200/200.jpg">
  
  <img src="https://i.picsum.photos/id/45/200/200.jpg">
  <img src="https://i.picsum.photos/id/58/200/200.jpg">
  <img src="https://i.picsum.photos/id/613/200/200.jpg">
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks Rickard! I like the way this looks. Seems like there's no way to do it without having some sort of spacing on the sides but it still looks good.

Comment: You don't need to have those spaces, but then you need to "hard code" spacing for images 2 (padding-right), 3 (padding-right), and 4 (padding-left & padding-right – the middle of the three), instead of writing a general left and right spacing for all images. It all depends on how dynamic you want this.